# mongodb $near query if document has geolocation

Tags: mongodb, geojson

i cannot use the $near uery within an $or. The problem is, that not every document has a geolocation, so currently i want to  find all document that are within a range or that do not have a geolocation. Is there a way to accomplish this in one query? Or do i have to create a temporary table?

Comment: This behaviour will happen by default as `$near`, if a document does not have that field then it won't be searched on.

Comment: But i want that document to be in tthe result set as i don't know if it fits from the missing location, the end user will have to check himself

Comment: you have to split it into 2 queries, one for the $near and one for the field does not exist.